# Famous type of transistor in IC

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit

I am begginer in electronics and I would like to ask if there is a specific type of a transistor which is used more than the others in today integrated circuits and why?

Comment: you use different types of transistors for different problems. Your question is hence nonsensical, sorry. "IC" says exactly nothing about which types of transistors will be necessary to implement it. For example, a RF transceiver & DSP IC (like the AD9361) will contain silicon BJT, JFET, MOSFETs, and, depending on what the frontend needs to achieve, some high-speed non-silicon transistors, which will, technically, be BJT, but look different on the die (because done on different substrate at different structure size).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Fame is somewhat subjective so answers will be opinion-based.

Comment: None of them are famous, they do their job without recognition or fame, Poor things. Now among discrete transistors, the 2N3055 is famous...

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to rewrite the question a little better.

Comment: @BrianDrummond, before this question all gets deleted, let's not forget the OC71 and BC108, got us from the summer of love right through to hip-hop...

Comment: If the OP edited his question to just famous transistors he might get many many votes .

Comment: @autistic :-D Too right :-D

Answer (score 2):

Most transistors are [CMOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS), by quantity. ICs like the Intel i7 use billions per chip. Ditto SRAM memories.